# Translate MSDN example from C# to C++/CLI

Tags: c#, c++-cli, code-translation

this is a code sample from Microsoft(MSDN) [(build sql dependency application)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a52dhwx7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) , could you please help me translate this code from c# into C++/CLI, I've been trying I, but I'm not really good in c++.

```
private void dependency_OnChange(
   object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{
    // This event will occur on a thread pool thread.
    // Updating the UI from a worker thread is not permitted.
    // The following code checks to see if it is safe to
    // update the UI.
    ISynchronizeInvoke i = (ISynchronizeInvoke)this;

    // If InvokeRequired returns True, the code
    // is executing on a worker thread.
    if (i.InvokeRequired)
    {
        // Create a delegate to perform the thread switch.
        OnChangeEventHandler tempDelegate =
            new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

        object[] args = { sender, e };

        // Marshal the data from the worker thread
        // to the UI thread.
        i.BeginInvoke(tempDelegate, args);

        return;
    }

    // Remove the handler, since it is only good
    // for a single notification.
    SqlDependency dependency =
        (SqlDependency)sender;

    dependency.OnChange -= dependency_OnChange;

    // At this point, the code is executing on the
    // UI thread, so it is safe to update the UI.
    ++changeCount;
    label1.Text = changeCount;

}
```

Comment: This is part of a much bigger piece of code; I don't suggest you post it all, but it will not be possible to convert this in isolation and have it make any sense!

Comment: Pure C++ or C++/CLI? This would be impossile in simple C++ withou use of additional libraries.

Comment: Can you provide a link from where you took this code

Comment: yes, into c++/cli
and here is the original link of microsoft 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a52dhwx7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Why not just compile it in C# and reference that assembly from C++/CLI?

Comment: coz I don't wont only to use it, I want also to learn how would it be in C++

Comment: Can you build this into assembly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my quick attempt:

```
private void dependency_OnChange(
   System::Object^ sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs^ e)
{
    // This event will occur on a thread pool thread.
    // Updating the UI from a worker thread is not permitted.
    // The following code checks to see if it is safe to
    // update the UI.
    ISynchronizeInvoke^ i = this;

    // If InvokeRequired returns True, the code
    // is executing on a worker thread.
    if (i->InvokeRequired)
    {
        // Create a delegate to perform the thread switch.
        OnChangeEventHandler^ tempDelegate =
            gcnew OnChangeEventHandler(this, &Form1::dependency_OnChange);

        cli::array<System::Object^>^ args = gcnew cli::array<System::Object^>(2);
        args[0] = sender;
        args[1] = e;

        // Marshal the data from the worker thread
        // to the UI thread.
        i->BeginInvoke(tempDelegate, args);

        return;
    }

    // Remove the handler, since it is only good
    // for a single notification.
    SqlDependency^ dependency = safe_cast<SqlDependency^>(sender);

    dependency->OnChange -= gcnew OnChangeEventHandler(this, &Form1::dependency_OnChange);

    // At this point, the code is executing on the
    // UI thread, so it is safe to update the UI.
    ++changeCount;
    label1->Text = changeCount.ToString();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Compile the C# sample source code, then use [Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/) to decompile the assembly to MC++ (managed C++).

Comment: MC++ != C++/CLI.  Forget that Managed Extensions for C++ ever existed.